# I used Bumblebee to ruin my display resolution. How can I change it back to default settings?

Tags: nvidia, resolution, bumblebee

I have an Nvidia 470 and Ubuntu looked great OOB. I tried Bumblebee to install Nvidia drivers, and the resolution went from  great to lousy.

How can I change my resolution back to the default, without re-installing Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

- Press   `ctrl+alt+F1` ,it opens console.
- Login into the console by putting your `Username` and `Password`.
- After logged in run the below commands,

  `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
  `sudo shutdown -h now`
- After power on your pc,you will getback to your original resolution.